# Python Scrapy: How do i use self.download_delay

Tags: python, scrapy

I've never used Scrapy.
Please help!

I want to make a delay for each request in the "next_link"

Example:

GET https://example.com/?page=1

delay 30 seconds

GET https://example.com/?page=2

delay 30 seconds

```
class CVSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cvspider'
    start_urls = ["login"]
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0,
        'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': True
    }

    def __init__(self, search_url, name=None, **kwargs):
        self.search_url = search_url

    def parse(self, response):
        xsrf = response.css('input[name="_xsrf"] ::attr(value)')\
                       .extract_first()
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'username': USERNAME,
                'password': PASSWORD,
                '_xsrf': xsrf
            },
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Parse %s', response.url)
        if "account/login" in response.url:
            self.logger.error("Login failed!")
            return

        return scrapy.Request(self.search_url, callback=self.parse_search_page)

    def parse_search_page(self, response):
        cv_hashes = response\
            .css('table.output tr[itemscope="itemscope"]::attr(data-hash)')\
            .extract()
        total = len(cv_hashes)
        start_time = datetime.now()
        next_link = response.css('a.Controls-Next::attr(href)')\
                            .extract_first()
        if total == 0:
            next_link = None
        if next_link is not None:
            self.download_delay = 30 - does not work
            yield scrapy.Request(
                "https://example.com" + next_link,
                callback=self.parse_search_page
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting option to achieve this. In `settings.py` file, set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`, like this :

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 30000  # Time in milliseconds (30000 ms = 30 seconds)
```

But remember to remove `custom_settings` from your code.

---

If you want to do this with custom setting for that `Spider`, then modify your code like this :

```
class CVSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cvspider'
    start_urls = ["login"]
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 30000,
        'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': False
    }

    def __init__(self, search_url, name=None, **kwargs):
    ...
```

You can refer to the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.22/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY) for more understanding on that.

Comment: DOWNLOAD_DELAY is set for all requests, but I need only for:

 self.download_delay = 30 - does not work
 yield scrapy.Request(

Comment: You can use `sleep()` here ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to only setup the `download_delay` variable in your spider, and scrapy will do the rest, you don't need to actually "use" it.

so just set it up like:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
  ...
  download_delay = 30000
  ...
```

that's it.

Comment: I want to set a delay only for parse_search_page func